# Generate XML file and attach it in email (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, xml, typescript, email-attachments, nodemailer

How one can create an XML file and attach it in email by using nodemailer?

This is the format of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CaseData>
   <CaseNo>329388m1</CaseNo>
</CaseData>
```

The code to compose an email:

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: 'andreifletcherssolicitors@gmail.com',
    to: '97andreienache@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Test',
    text: 'Hello World!'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xmlbuilder` to make it easier to generate xml

```js
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var obj = {
  CaseData: {
    CaseNo: '329388m1'
  }
};

var xml = builder.create(obj).end({ pretty: true});
console.log(xml);
```

and then attach it with nodemailer like this

```js
let message = {
    ...
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: 'myxmlfile.xml',
            content: xmlStringAbove,
            contentType: 'text/xml'
        }
    ]
}
```